# how to insert data in an existing table after useing foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

i tried many times but i don't understand how can we insert data in already existing table with data after using (alter) foreign key constraint.i am using my SQL workbench (8.0).can we have to insert data again or data can only be added after foreign key constraint.

Comment: Data can be added as long as it does not break the rules of the constraint. Basically you must add a parent or have an existing parent before you can add a child

Comment: You shouldn't have to add data again if the relationships are already correct. And if they aren't correct, it won't let you add the constraint.

Comment: i create a table name employee_detail where i set empid as primary key and create another table name branch. after that i insert the data in these table. i forgot to add empid as foreign key so i use alter table contraint for foreign key. and foreign key is created successfully but the data in foreign key column(empid) is null. how can i insert data in it now.

Comment: There is no relation. The data may be added into the table both before and after FK creation. But when after then the data must match FK condition.

Comment: Start by reading about [LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id). It is a way to get the id of a row inserted in one table to set the fk in another, dependent, table.